# Праскова и Прасковья

Tags: этимология

Встретил в болгарском языке слово "праскова" - персик (ж. р.) и соответственно вспомнил похожее слово в русском - Прасковья (имя). В болгарском очень много слов, которые были в русском ранее и как-то затерялись. Дилетантский подход, но нет ли связи между этими словами?
А то по словарям и Википедии - у нас весь русский язык и научная терминология заимствованы из греческого, разве что мы сами еще не греки. Уж лучше в дилетанты.

Answer (score 1):

```
 А то по словарям и Википедии - у нас весь русский язык  и  научная 
терминология заимствованы из греческого, разве что мы сами еще не греки.
```

Ну, знаете, если не пользоваться словарями, то придётся в древние памятники письменности погружаться или фантазировать. Похожих слов в языках много, но часто это просто совпадение. Если вспомнить, как славяне или конкретно на Руси (языческие времена не берём, имя  Прасковья не языческое - христианское) давали имена младенцам, придётся признать, что в основном по святцам. Грецизмов в религиозной литературе много. Значит, словари правы, а они утверждают, что имя Прасковья греческого происхождения.

> Скорее всего произошло от древнегреческого «παρα-σκευή», что звучит
>   как Параскева. Буквальная трактовка звучит как «канун субботы», "канун
>   праздника" или «пятница». Впрочем, существуют и другие, но менее
>   популярные версии (долгожданная, ожидаемая, предпраздничная).
>   Подробнее на https://namedb.ru/name/praskovya/

День ангела и святые покровители имени - две Параскевы: имя дважды в году отмечает именины.

> •8 августа (26 июля) – Св. мученица Параскева-римлянка пострадала за
>   Христа во II в.
>
> •27 (14) октября - Св. великомученица Параскева, нареченная Пятница. Родилась Параскева во время правления императора Диоклетиана. Её родители очень чтили пятницу, день, когда был распят Господь, поэтому так и назвали свою дочь – в честь дня недели (пятница). Она  распространяла веру Христову среди язычников своего города (Иконии) и
>   помогала бедным, нищим и странникам; претерпела за это великие мучения  и  была обезглавлена (III в.).

У славянских народов образ святой Параскевы Пятницы слился с образом  языческой богини Пятницы, покровительницы плодородия, женского
 рукоделия и домашних животных. Не в последнюю очередь поэтому  Параскева Пятница считается небесной покровительницей домашнего скота,
 а также ткачей и прях (из уважения к святой Пятнице женщины на Руси  старались по пятницам не прясть и не ткать).

Есть это имя и в католическом именослове, в других странах «тезками» Прасковьи являются греческая и болгарская Параскева, немецкая Парачевула, польская Прасцвея, английская Пэраскиви.

Кстати, в Болгарии есть и мужское имя:

ж. Параскева, Парашкева, уменьшительные - Кета, Кева, Пека, Паца, Паша, Пара, Паруша

м. Параскев, Парашкев, уменьшительные - Параско, Паро

У них  популярны имена Петка и Петко (букв. перевод греч. Παρασκευή).